# Marquee issue in HTML

Tags: html, marquee

I want to Create a Marquee that when text Exit from one Side and show on other side

like i have code something like that

all marquee text came on the sametime, and i want to be one by one

```
<div class="flash_ac">
    <marquee align="left" truespeed="10">
     news1
     news2
     news3
    </marquee>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What decade are you living in? The 1990's still?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xAGRJ/4/

Answer (score -1):

You're missing some code inside that tag.
You need:
behavior=
bgcolor=
loop=
width=
scrollamount=

Comment: Without mentioning that `<marquee>` tags should not be used under any circumstances, all of these attributes have [default vaules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) or are unnecessary.